# Was there ever a proposal to include the URL fragment into the HTTP request?

Tags: http, url, http-headers, fragment-identifier

In the current HTTP spec, the URL fragment (the part of the URL including and following the `#`) is not sent to the server in any way. However with the increased spread of AJAX, which uses the fragment to maintain some form of state, there are a lot of situations where it would be useful for the server to have knowledge of the URL fragment at request time.

For example, if you go to http://facebook.com, then click a user name in your stream, the URL will become http://faceboook.com/#!/username - to allow FB to update your page without reloading all of its bootstrap JS and HTML. However, if you were to reload this with your browser, the server would have no way of seeing the "#/!username" part of the URL, and therefore could not pre-render the content for you. This forces your browser to make an extra request once the client Javascript has loaded and parsed the fragment.

I am wondering if there have been any efforts or proposals towards creating a standard mechanism to achieve this.

For example, there could be a standard HTTP header, which would be sent with the value of the URL fragment - any server which cared about such things could then have access to it.

It seems like this would be a very useful thing for the web-application community as a whole, so I am surprised to not have heard anything proposed. Perhaps I missed it though.

Comment: Do you have an example where a query string won't do the job?

Comment: How do you claim that 'ajax uses the fragment for state'? Lots of stateful things do all the state maintaining they need with the base URL or query string.

Comment: I added an example in the second paragraph of how FB uses the fragment to reflect current state. Using a URL param in this instance would force the application to reload itself on every view transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this proposal by Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html) to make Ajax pages crawlable, but it addresses a more constrained set of use cases. Specifically, it creates a way to replace the URL fragment with a URL parameter to obtain the same HTML output from the server as would be generated by a client visiting the equivalent URL with the fragment. However, such URLs are useless for actually running the Ajax apps, since they would necessitate a page reload every time.

Answer (score 1):

Imho, the fragment identifier really is not a good place to store the state, it has been designed for something else.

That being said, http://www.jenitennison.com/blog/node/154 has a good discussion of the whole subject.

Answer (score 0):

Webkit [Bug 24175 - URL Redirect Loses Fragment](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24175) refers to [Handling of fragment identifiers in redirected URLs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Fragment/draft-bos-http-redirect-00.txt) which may be of interest.

> A suggestion for a future version of HTTP may be to add an (optional)
>   Fragment header to the request, which holds the fragment identifier.
>
> Even simpler may be to allow an HTTP request to contain a fragment
>   identifier.